# What is the difference between regular IATA number and IATA TIDS?

Tags: iata

I am a software developer and trying to understand the aviation domain because I see some very interesting opportunities after seeing airlines adopting NDC standard for their distribution.

I am trying to understand the difference between an IATA number and IATA TIDS number which is issued by IATA which is also used for identifying travel agents globally. As far as I know that an agency has to pay very huge amount of guarantees to IATA to get an IATA number, but IATA TIDS is free of cost. What is the difference between them and what are the benefits of IATA which are not included in TIDS?

Thanks

Comment: You should delete the post on the Aviation Stack unless it has already been closed there.

Comment: @mdewey I deleted my post on aviation.se

Comment: Aviation.SE would probably be a better fit, but let's see what TSE says...

Comment: [This page](https://www.iata.org/en/services/accreditation/) has some pointers. Apparently IATA number is superset of TIDS.

Comment: @lambshaanxy the OP is in a catch 22 at the moment. [aviation.se] already said it is a travel question ( in that travel agent id's are being asked about ).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per the [IATA website](https://www.iata.org/en/services/accreditation/tids/faq/):

> What is the difference between the IATA Accreditation and TIDS Programs?
> The IATA Accreditation and TIDS programs both facilitate the identification of bookings and reservations with industry suppliers such as airlines, hotels, and car rental companies.

> TIDS agents however cannot issue airline tickets through IATA’s BSP (Billing and Settlement Plan), whereas IATA Accredited Agents are able to do so.